# How do I automate wrapping methods?

Tags: javascript

I would like to automatically wrap all methods in an object with a function.
For now, I only know how to do it one by one:

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4VuE7/

code:

```
<div style=white-space:pre>
<i>foo bar lorem ipsum</i>
<i>foo bar lorem ipsum</i>
<i>foo bar lorem ipsum</i>
<i>foo bar lorem ipsum</i>
<i>foo bar lorem ipsum</i>
<i>foo bar lorem ipsum</i>
</div>​
<script>

//method that only works on elements:
Element.prototype.css = function(a,i,n){for(n in''+a===a||a)this.style[n]=a[n];return i||n?(this.style[a]=i,this):getComputedStyle(this)[a]};

//put a wrapper around it that makes it work with nodelists
NodeList.prototype.css = function(a,i){for(var n in this)this[n].css(a,i)};

//put a wrapper around it so it works with a selector in a string
String.prototype.css = function(a,i){document.querySelectorAll(this).css(a,i)}​;

//use the method:

"div>i".css("color","red")​;​

</script>
```

I would like to do this automatically for every method in the object. (a single function wraps every method automatically)

disclaimer: Don't mess around with the dom unless you really know what you are doing! (You probably don't!) This example is for demonstration purposes only.

Comment: Be aware that extending `Element.prototype` and `NodeList.prototype` is considered a very bad practice with huge inconsistencies across browsers. This is why modern libraries such as jQuery require you to wrap these objects with `$()` before you can use methods on them.

Comment: http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/ is a good article about the disadvantages of extending the DOM. That said, I don't really understand your question.

Comment: @Mattias Buelens Be aware that I don't care about this. I'm doing this for fun and I would never use this for client work :) I'm basically experimenting with making a library that makes the dom suck less. I just use the built in prototypes because it makes a shorter example.

Comment: @FelixKling I don't care, if you want to know why, look at my reply above.

Comment: @williammalo All right then. Perhaps you should clear that up in your question, otherwise some newbie may actually think this is a good idea. Now, could you explain what you mean by "wrap all methods in an object with a function"?

Comment: @MattiasBuelens Completely sure!

Comment: @MattiasBuelens Isn't it clear in my example? [quote]could you explain what you mean by "wrap all methods in an object with a function"?[/quote]

Comment: @williammalo Not really. In your example, I see you are extending the prototype of three different classes one by one with a method calls `css`. I have absolutely no idea what you mean with wrapping them in an object with a function. Could you update your question with some kind of pseudo-code or an expected result?

Comment: @MattiasBuelens Notice how I only define the .css method() ounce. after that, I wrap the method in a function that allows it to do more things, but I never change the original method.

Comment: @williammalo There's no relationship between `Element.prototype.css` and `NodeList.prototype.css`, they're just different methods. Every implementation defines how the `css` method works for this particular class, and luckily they can re-use previously defined `css` methods of other classes. So I honestly have no idea what you're getting at with automatically wrapping them in a function that does more.

Answer (score 0):

I found how to do it!: http://jsfiddle.net/4VuE7/3/

```
Element.prototype.css = function(a,i,n){
for(n in''+a===a||a)this.style[n]=a[n];return i||n?(this.style[a]=i,this):getComputedStyle(this)[a]};

Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Element.prototype).forEach(function(a){

    NodeList.prototype[a]=function(){for(var n in this)this[n][a].apply(this[n],arguments)}

    String.prototype[a]=function(){document.querySelectorAll(this)[a].apply(document.querySelectorAll(this),arguments)}

});


"div>i".css("color","red");​
```

Comment: Ooh, so you wanted to define more methods with other names which are mapped in a similar fashion to the `Element.prototype` version of the method. Now I get it. It would probably have been easier if you gave an example with more than one such method, e.g. `css`, `width` and `height` methods. That way, we might have noticed the similarities you wanted to automate.